# Is there any difference between "sh -c 'some comand'" and directly run some command

Tags: shell, sh

let's say echo command, we can run that command by two ways:

```
# by 1
echo 'hello'
# or by 2
sh -c "echo 'hello'"
```

Is there any difference between the two ways? By the way, I can see the way 2 is very popular in yaml config files.

```
- name: init-mydb
  image: busybox:1.28
  command: ['sh', '-c', "sleep 2; done"]
```

Comment: The `command` key requires a *single* command and its arguments, not a command list. `sh -c` is basically a way to specify an arbitrary *series* of shell commands as a single argument to the command `sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way calls an inherited command interpreter, eg from a terminal running `/bin/bash` ; the second way exec `sh` (aka Bourne Shell) as the interpreter and instruct him ( `-c` ) to do something.

`sh`, `ksh`, `csh`, `bash` are all shell interpreters. They provide some features that are not always compatible between them. So, if you don't know the environment where your program will run, the best is to specify the interpreter you want, which is less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a single command:

```
foo 1 2 3
```

So is this

```
sh -c 'foo 1 2 3'
```

This is *not* a single command (but rather a pair of commands separated by a `;`)

```
foo; bar
```

but this is

```
sh -c "foo; bar"
```

This does not specify a command using the name of a executable file

```
for x in 1 2 3; do echo "$x"; done
```

but this does

```
sh -c 'for x in 1 2 3; do echo "$x"; done'
```

`sh -c` is basically way to specify an arbitrary shell *script* as a single argument to a command that can be executed from a file.